# Trigger a lambda function when partitioned file gets written

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am trying to trigger a lambda function when a Glue job finishes partionning a file and writes it on S3. 
My glue job does this:

```
df.repartition(10).write.format("csv").option("sep",",").option("header", "true").option("mode","Overwrite").save("s3://Bucket/a/b/c")
```

I created a trigger with the following parameters:

[image]

I putted `run` as prefix because my Glue job generates partions starting all with `run-`.

I am now doubting that my Lambda function isn't starting at all when Glue job finishes. (I want Lambda to run for all of the files partitions.

Where exactly can I see the history of my Lambda ? I am clearly a newbie on AWS.

Thank you

Comment: If your AWS Lambda function has been [given permission to write to CloudWatch Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html), you can view logs by going to the function's **monitoring tab** and clicking "View Logs in CloudWatch". There are also charts in the Monitoring tab showing executions and errors.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Rotenstein said, logs and execution history are found in monitoring tab in the lambda function page.